# Pass object or pointer as value when not changing that object in function

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

In c++ there are multiple ways of passing an object as parameter to a function. I have been reading up on passing by value and reference.

These links were very useful:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

And in the case of c++, which I am wondering about now, I saw this article as well:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

These go into the differences between passing by value and reference. And this last article also depicts a few pros and cons on the matter. I would like to know though the pros and cons of passing a parameter as a value in the case the object is not modified in the function.

```
int f(sockaddr_in s) {
// Don't change anything about s
}

int f(sockaddr_in *s) {
// Don't change anything about s
}
```

Both allow me to access the variables it has. But I would like to know which one I should use, and why.

Comment: In the second example do you mean `int f(sockaddr_in &s) {` to pass by reference and not `*s`?, otherwise you are passing a pointer, its not quite the same.

Comment: There's no pass-by-reference here. Apart from that, a pointer (or a reference) is often passed so that copying the entire object can be avoided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Comment: @stijn that is a really helpful link. To bad I didn't find that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example `f()` obtains a copy of the original object and hence cannot possibly change the latter. However, the copy constructor is invoked, which may be quite expensive and is therefore not advisable as a general method.

In the second example `f()` either obtains a pointer or (for `f(obj&x)`) a reference to the original object and is allowed to modify it. If the function only takes a `const` pointer or reference, as in `f(const object&x)`, it cannot legally change the object. Here, no copy is made. Therefore, passing by const reference is the standard approach for parameter that shall not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring a fundamental thing of c++: const correctness: The declaration 'int f(sockaddr_in *s)' violates that. The 'int f(sockaddr_in s)' does not and might be reasonable (sockaddr_in is small or copied anyway). Hence, both 'int f(const sockaddr_in& s)' and 'int f(sockaddr_in s)' might be a good choice.